# getVisibleText() from value=test

Tags: intern

I have this problem, i need to get text from value=test to compare it with exact text:

```
.setFindTimeout(2000)
.findDisplayedByCss('firstname')
.getVisibleText()
.then(function (text) {
assert.strictEqual(text, 'test');
})
.end()


AssertionError: expected ' ' to equal 'test'
```

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: i have found the solution : 
   .setFindTimeout(2000)
                .findDisplayedByCssSelector('input[name="firstname"]')
                .getAttribute("placeholder")
                .then(function (text) {
                    assert.strictEqual('First name', text);
                })
                .getAttribute("value")
                .then(function (text) {
                    assert.strictEqual('test2', text);

Answer (score 1):

I have found a solution :

```
.setFindTimeout(2000)
.findDisplayedByCssSelector('input[name="firstname"]')
.getAttribute("placeholder")
.then(function (text) {
    assert.strictEqual('First name', text);
})
.getAttribute("value")
.then(function (text) {
    assert.strictEqual('test2', text);
```